# JsonIgnore attributes not working in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I've got an object in my project with circular references. I've put [JsonIgnore] above the field like so:

```
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Foobar ChildObject { get; set; }
```

I'm still getting circular reference errors when I serialize the object. The only fields that do not have JsonIgnore are string fields and should not cause this. Is there something else I need to do to get JsonIgnore to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Just got back from vacation, I will look at this tonight and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use [ScriptIgnore] as [JsonIgnore] seems to not be implemented.

Comment: For more information about why JsonIgnore is not working. You might need to know the differences between ASP.NET WebAPI and ASP.NET MVC. * Why JsonIgnore is not working: the two are not using the same Please also refer to the following answers. serializer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160530/jsonignore-not-working-in-system-web-mvc-controller And this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591750/setting-the-default-json-serializer-in-asp-net-mvc *btw, sry, I wanted to put this references to comments, but having no reputation to do so

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You likely have some other property that links back to its parent. Use the `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` setting to prevent self-referencing loops.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

JsonSerializerSettings jsSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foobars, Formatting.None, jsSettings);
```

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for this; several mentions that Newtonsoft supports ignoring circular references and no mention of the actual property to set. Thanks!

Comment: thanks But how do I keep using `JSon(models,"text/json",JsonRequestBehavior.AlloGet)` ?

Comment: @Bellash I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: @Bellash, you can use something like `return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foobars, Formatting.None, jsSettings), "application/json");`

Comment: Just received a downvote for this. I would appreciate constructive criticism as to why this is not a useful answer to the question.

Comment: It seems this is necessary even if you use [JsonIgnore] on the property that contains the loops.

Answer (score 91):

I had incorrectly resolved the JsonIgnore reference.

Note that this attribute exists in more than one namespace:

- System.Text.Json.Serialization
- Newtonsoft.Json

I had resolved this in VS to **System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore** - however I was using the Newtonsoft library for my actual Serialise/Deserialise - and hence the attribute was ignored.
Changing the reference to **Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore** resolved.

Comment: I am now using both attributes in both namespaces.  ASP.NET uses "system.Text.json" variety when you return `Json(model)` from an MVC Action

Answer (score 4):

If anyone needs an ASP.Net Core implementation of ignore child references, here it is.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...

    services.AddMvc()


         .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

    ...
}
```

src: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Answer (score 1):

Using this one solved my issue

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
```