# Setting the default JSON serializer in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I'm working on an existing application that has been partially converted over to MVC.  Whenever a controller responds with a JSON ActionResult, the enums are sent as numbers opposed to the string name.  It sounds like the default serializer should be JSON.Net, which should be sending the enums over as their names opposed to the integer representation, but that's not the case here.

Am I missing a web.config setting that sets this as the default serializer?  Or is there another setting that needs to be changed?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In ASP.Net MVC4 the default JavaScript serializer which is used in the `JsonResult` class is still the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) (you can check it in the [code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5cb74eb3b2f3#src/System.Web.Mvc/JsonResult.cs))

I think you have confused it with the ASP.Net Web.API where JSON.Net is the default JS serializer but MVC4 doesn't use it.

So you need to configure JSON.Net to work with MVC4 (basically you need to create your own `JsonNetResult`), there are plenty of articles about it:

- [ASP.NET MVC and Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx)
- [Using JSON.NET as the default JSON serializer in ASP.NET MVC 3 - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109967/using-json-net-as-default-json-serializer-in-asp-net-mvc-3-is-it-possible)

If you also want to use JSON.Net for controller action parameters so during the model binding then you need write your own `ValueProviderFactory` implementation.

And you need to register your implementation with:

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories
    .Remove(ValueProviderFactories.Factories
                                  .OfType<JsonValueProviderFactory>().Single());
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new MyJsonValueProviderFactory());
```

You can use the built in `JsonValueProviderFactory` as an example or this article:  [ASP.NET MVC 3 – Improved JsonValueProviderFactory using Json.Net](http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2012/01/10/asp-net-mvc-3-improved-jsonvalueproviderfactory-using-json-net/)

Comment: That helps with sending JSON responses, but not with deserializing incoming JSON as the framework attempts to map incoming calls into parameters passed into your action methods . . . how do you change the serializer used by MVC for that purpose?

Comment: If you want to use Json.NET for incoming paramters you need write your own `ValueProviderFactory` implementation. You can use the built in `JsonValueProviderFactory` as an example. And you need to register your implementation with:  `ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Remove(
                ValueProviderFactories.Factories.OfType<JsonValueProviderFactory>().Single());
            ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new MyJsonValueProviderFactory());`. See also: http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2012/01/10/asp-net-mvc-3-improved-jsonvalueproviderfactory-using-json-net/

Comment: +1 for how to bind controller action parameters, most question/answers i find are about just sending JSON.

Comment: I used a slightly modified version of the referenced code, and on an action with a single string input, like `public ResultObject DoThis(string input)` the line `JSONReader.Read` dies with an exception like "Inappropriate character, the text isn't JSON".  Weirder is that as a URL param it's fine, but it throws in the POST body.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @drzaus to answer my question, it seems that a form-data encoded request, rather than a raw JSON (via [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)), will trigger my issue, since it tries to deserialize essentially gibberish

Comment: @nemesv Is JavaScript serializer the default serializer in MVC 5?

Comment: @Marc according to the source code: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/JsonResult.cs the `JsonResult` in MVC5 still uses the old `JavaScriptSerializer` and **does not** uses JSON.net

Comment: When I try to register the new ValueProvider I get an error in the Factories.OfType. It says the OfType does not exist. Does this still work in MVC4?

Comment: @jpgrassi `OfType` is an extension method definied in the `System.Linq` namespace. Do you have the `using System.Linq;` in your cs file?

Comment: Yeah forgot about that. Solved now!

Comment: For the record, MVC 6 finally uses Json.NET as the default.

Comment: clarify ambiguity,  public override System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)

Answer (score 7):

**ASP.NET MVC 5 Fix:**

I wasn't ready to change to Json.NET just yet and in my case the error was occurring during the request. Best approach in my scenario was modifying the actual `JsonValueProviderFactory` which applies the fix to the global project and can be done by editing the `global.cs` file as such.

```
JsonValueProviderConfig.Config(ValueProviderFactories.Factories);
```

add a web.config entry:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonLength" value="20971520" />
```

and then create the two following classes

```
public class JsonValueProviderConfig
{
    public static void Config(ValueProviderFactoryCollection factories)
    {
        var jsonProviderFactory = factories.OfType<JsonValueProviderFactory>().Single();
        factories.Remove(jsonProviderFactory);
        factories.Add(new CustomJsonValueProviderFactory());
    }
}
```

This is basically an exact copy of the default implementation found in `System.Web.Mvc` but with the addition of a configurable web.config appsetting value `aspnet:MaxJsonLength`.

```
public class CustomJsonValueProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
{

    /// <summary>Returns a JSON value-provider object for the specified controller context.</summary>
    /// <returns>A JSON value-provider object for the specified controller context.</returns>
    /// <param name="controllerContext">The controller context.</param>
    public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");

        object deserializedObject = CustomJsonValueProviderFactory.GetDeserializedObject(controllerContext);
        if (deserializedObject == null)
            return null;

        Dictionary<string, object> strs = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        CustomJsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(new CustomJsonValueProviderFactory.EntryLimitedDictionary(strs), string.Empty, deserializedObject);

        return new DictionaryValueProvider<object>(strs, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }

    private static object GetDeserializedObject(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        if (!controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return null;

        string fullStreamString = (new StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream)).ReadToEnd();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullStreamString))
            return null;

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer()
        {
            MaxJsonLength = CustomJsonValueProviderFactory.GetMaxJsonLength()
        };
        return serializer.DeserializeObject(fullStreamString);
    }

    private static void AddToBackingStore(EntryLimitedDictionary backingStore, string prefix, object value)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> strs = value as IDictionary<string, object>;
        if (strs != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in strs)
                CustomJsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(backingStore, CustomJsonValueProviderFactory.MakePropertyKey(prefix, keyValuePair.Key), keyValuePair.Value);

            return;
        }

        IList lists = value as IList;
        if (lists == null)
        {
            backingStore.Add(prefix, value);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lists.Count; i++)
        {
            CustomJsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(backingStore, CustomJsonValueProviderFactory.MakeArrayKey(prefix, i), lists[i]);
        }
    }

    private class EntryLimitedDictionary
    {
        private static int _maximumDepth;

        private readonly IDictionary<string, object> _innerDictionary;

        private int _itemCount;

        static EntryLimitedDictionary()
        {
            _maximumDepth = CustomJsonValueProviderFactory.GetMaximumDepth();
        }

        public EntryLimitedDictionary(IDictionary<string, object> innerDictionary)
        {
            this._innerDictionary = innerDictionary;
        }

        public void Add(string key, object value)
        {
            int num = this._itemCount + 1;
            this._itemCount = num;
            if (num > _maximumDepth)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.");
            }
            this._innerDictionary.Add(key, value);
        }
    }

    private static string MakeArrayKey(string prefix, int index)
    {
        return string.Concat(prefix, "[", index.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "]");
    }

    private static string MakePropertyKey(string prefix, string propertyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
        {
            return propertyName;
        }
        return string.Concat(prefix, ".", propertyName);
    }

    private static int GetMaximumDepth()
    {
        int num;
        NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
        if (appSettings != null)
        {
            string[] values = appSettings.GetValues("aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers");
            if (values != null && values.Length != 0 && int.TryParse(values[0], out num))
            {
                return num;
            }
        }
        return 1000;
    }

    private static int GetMaxJsonLength()
    {
        int num;
        NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
        if (appSettings != null)
        {
            string[] values = appSettings.GetValues("aspnet:MaxJsonLength");
            if (values != null && values.Length != 0 && int.TryParse(values[0], out num))
            {
                return num;
            }
        }
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Added these two classes in our application and it worked. Thanks a lot, man, you've saved us a lot of time and trouble.

Comment: There was an error in the error message in if (num > _maximumDepth). It is not MaxJsonLength but MaxJsonDeserializerMembers property. Your code save me. ;)

Comment: Simply magnificient solution