# Ajax data into MVC model

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Our very simple models:

```
public class OrderSubmissionProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}

public class OrderSubmissionViewModel
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public OrderSubmissionProductViewModel[] Products { get; set; }
}
```

The AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: self.urlSubmitOrder,
    data: JSON.stringify({ submission: submission }),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function () { alert("Submitted"); },
    fail: function () { alert("Failed"); }
});
```

The MVC controller has this method signature:

```
public ActionResult SubmitAdminOrder(OrderSubmissionViewModel submission)
{ ... }
```

This is what the POST looks like:

```
{"submission":{"CustomerId":43,"AccountId":"20000","Products":[{"Id":4,"Price":100,"Qty":1},{"Id":6,"Price":14,"Qty":1}]}}
```

I can hit a breakpoint in the controller method, and the model is not null, but all of its properties are default values.  It's not getting bound correctly.  What am I doing wrong?

We're using ASP.Net MVC 4.

Comment: can you try just by sending JSON.stringify({ submission })?

Comment: I recommend you working with webapi-angularjs and forget aspMVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `submission` object isn't empty and can you try adding a `contentType` to the ajax options?

```
$.ajax({
    url: self.urlSubmitOrder,
    data: JSON.stringify({ submission: submission }),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function () { alert("Submitted"); },
    fail: function () { alert("Failed"); }
});
```

Or take a look at this post [Pass viewmodel with two objects to controller using Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367659/pass-viewmodel-with-two-objects-to-controller-using-json/22368579#22368579)

Comment: I guess it was the `contentType`.  Thanks vbn.