# Cannot make TypeNameHandling work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, json.net

I have these two classes and an action method

```
public class A
{
    public int AProp { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public int BProp { get; set; }
}

public void TestAction(A a)
{
    if (!(a is B)) 
    {
        throw new Exception("Should be B!");
    }
}
```

In my Global.asax's `Application_Start` I have below line.

```
var setting = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
setting.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
```

And the json data I am posting is like below.

```
{$type: 'MyNamespace.B, MyAssembly', AProp: 1, BProp: 2}
```

When action is invoked I expect type of `a` param is `MyNamespace.B` but it is `MyNamespace.A` so the exception gets thrown.

I wrote below code and tested if `$type` and `TypeNameHandling` thing work fine, they work. Type of `objA` is `MyNamespace.A` and type of `objB` is `MyNamespace.B`

```
var json = @"{$type: 'MyNamespace.B, MyAssembly', AProp: 1, BProp: 2}";

var objA = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(A), new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None
});

var objB = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(A), new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
});
```

What's the proper way to handle inheritance with ASP.NET MVC Controllers' Action parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have set the `TypeNameHandling` setting on the ASP.NET Web API infrastructure, not ASP.NET MVC. So this will work for your Web API controllers.

ASP.NET MVC's default value provider factory doesn't use Json.NET. it uses the built-in [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you want it to use Json.NET you may check the [`following answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14591946/29407) in which a custom factory is implemented:

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Remove(ValueProviderFactories.Factories.OfType<JsonValueProviderFactory>().Single());
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new MyJsonValueProviderFactory());
```