# Deserialize property with a different name?

Tags: c#, json

I have an interface with exposes a property called `Pages`:

```
public interface INameSet
{
    IQueryable<string> Names { get; }
}
```

I have this class which implements the interface and must also be parsed from a JSON object:

```
[DataContract(Name = "surveyPageSet")]
public class SurveyPage : INameSet
{
    [DataMember(Name = "names")]
    public List<string> SurveyNames { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<string> Names
    {
        get
        {
            //Returns SurveyNames after some filtration logic
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I pass in this object:

```
{
    "names": ["testname"]
}
```

The JSON interpreter is trying to deserialize it to match the `Names` property instead of the `SurveyNames` property.  I know this happens because when removing the implementation of the interface and changing `SurveyNames` to `Names` it populates the property fine.  Is there any way to get it to serialize to the correct property or do I need to create a translator class that will generate the proper concretion of the `INameSet` interface?

EDIT: This is with the built-in serializer.  If there is a solution with Newtonsoft/JSON.NET that would be fine with me.

Comment: how do you serialize your object, maybe the attribute [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Names")] will help.

Comment: I'm not serializing it, it will come from an external source but the JSON i provided is a (an extremely simplified) mock of what will be received.  I will try this attribute though.

Comment: EDIT to above: I would prefer not to use Jackson if possible, I would be fine with JSON.NET but AFAIK Jackson isn't available through Nuget.

Comment: What serializer are you using?

Comment: The default JSON deserializer, if there is a way to do it through JSON.NET I would be okay with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JavaScriptSerializer` doesn't allow for remapping of names out of the box, so don't use it.

Instead, use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) or `DataContractJsonSerializer`.  In fact, both should *already* work given the data contract attributes you have applied.

For instance, using Json.NET, if I do:

```
        var page1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SurveyPage>(json);
        Debug.Assert(page1.SurveyNames != null && page1.SurveyNames.SequenceEqual(new string [] { "testname" }));
```

Then there is no assert.  Similarly there is no assert if I do:

```
        var page2 = DataContractJsonSerializerHelper.GetObject<SurveyPage>(json);
        Debug.Assert(page2.SurveyNames != null && page2.SurveyNames.SequenceEqual(new string[] { "testname" }));
```

using the helper class:

```
public static class DataContractJsonSerializerHelper
{
    private static MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
    {
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value ?? ""));
    }

    public static string GetJson<T>(T obj, DataContractJsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(memory, obj);
            memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(memory))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    public static string GetJson<T>(T obj) where T : class
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return GetJson(obj, serializer);
    }

    public static T GetObject<T>(string json) where T : class
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return GetObject<T>(json, serializer);
    }

    public static T GetObject<T>(string json, DataContractJsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        T obj = default(T);
        using (var stream = GenerateStreamFromString(json))
        {
            obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

**Update**

If you really want to continue to use `JavaScriptConverter`, you can write your own [`JavaScriptConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and deserialize each field manually.  But it's a bother and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, is there a tutorial you could recommend for replacing the JavaScriptConverter provider with a JSON.NET provider?  The main reason I wanted to use the default provider was because it automatically deserialized objects in controller methods.

Comment: @jokulmorder - does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591750/asp-net-mvc4-setting-the-default-json-serializer