# c# DateTimeOffset parse ISO8601 wrong?

Tags: c#, datetime

In a MVC controller 
I have a class with a `public DateTimeOffset? Prop1 {get;set;}` 
The class is instantiated by json that was passed from a controller method. So the value passed in is a string of ISO8601 format "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+08:00".

For some reason the implicit conversion fails and returns null. I read somewhere that I have to use a "k custom formatter". How would i set that up as default for string->DateTimeOffset conversion?

Can i do it without explicitly calling TryParse?

Comment: you may try `"yyyy-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+08:00"` I doubt it's wrong format

Comment: mmm i think i explained wrong. Is it possible for the implicit conversion to happen without me having to specify the format string?

Comment: You want a `string` to be implicitly converted to a `DateTimeOffset`?

Answer (score 0):

In an MVC controller, the default JSON serializer is the `JavaScriptSerializer` - which does not understand ISO8601 formatted values.  It expects dates to be something like: `\/Date(1337020200000+0530)\`.  The `DataContractJsonSerializer` used with WCF applications also expects this format.

To support ISO8601, the easiest thing to do is to switch to ASP.Net WebAPI, which uses [JSON.Net](http://json.net) for serialization.  JSON.Net uses ISO8601 as the default (while still supporting the other format).

[Here is an old-but-good article describing the differences](http://techblog.dorogin.com/2012/05/json-serializers-in-aspnet-and-other.html).

If you must stick with an MVC Controller, you can replace the serializer with JSON.Net, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14591946/634824).

Also, it's worth noting that while WebAPI uses JSON.Net today, it is going to be used in MVC by default with the upcoming [ASP.Net vNext](http://www.asp.net/vnext).