# Serializing to JSON in LINQ query

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization, linq-to-entities

Hey I'm trying to receive data with Ajax in ASP.NET MVC, but this code doesn't seem to be working.

```
return this.Json(new
        {
            Result = (from obj in temp
                      select new
                      {
                          ObjektoAdresas = obj.ObjektoAdresas,
                          ĮrenginioNumeris = obj.ĮrenginioNumeris,
                          T1 = serializer.Serialize(obj.T1),
                          T2 = serializer.Serialize(obj.T2),
                          ŠiluminėEnergija = serializer.Serialize(obj.ŠiluminėEnergija),
                          ŠiluminėGalia = serializer.Serialize(obj.ŠiluminėGalia)
                      })
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This throws a NotSupportedException with additional information: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

As I understand I can't use serializer.Serialize(something) because it takes a parameter. Is that correct? And if so, how do I serialize this data to JSON before sending it?

EDIT: I changed the code after Will's response, but it still throws the same exception.

```
var temp = (from obj
                    in models
                    select obj).ToArray();

        return this.Json(new
        {
            Result = (from obj in temp
                      select new
                      {
                          ObjektoAdresas = obj.ObjektoAdresas,
                          ĮrenginioNumeris = obj.ĮrenginioNumeris,
                          T1 = serializer.Serialize(obj.T1),
                          T2 = serializer.Serialize(obj.T2),
                          //Srautas = serializer.Serialize(obj.Srautas),
                          //VandensKiekis = serializer.Serialize(obj.VandensKiekis),
                          ŠiluminėEnergija = serializer.Serialize(obj.ŠiluminėEnergija),
                          ŠiluminėGalia = serializer.Serialize(obj.ŠiluminėGalia)
                      })
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I think I misread things... Go through ALL your EF models and make sure none of them have constructors.

Comment: It throws when you call `ToArray`, correct?  Catch the exception, call ToString on it, and paste the result in an [edit], pls.

Comment: Why are you manually serializing the contained classes `T1`, `T2`, and so on?  When you do `return this.Json(...)` your object hierarchy gets serialized for you by the returned [`JsonResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), using [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591750/setting-the-default-json-serializer-in-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: But if I don't manually serialize the objects than the ajax call fails.

Comment: Sorry, but the problem wasn't in this piece of code, but rather in another place. I was selecting new KeyValuePairs and using the constructor to initialize them, so I changed that and now it works. Thanks for trying to help.