# Can MVC deserialize the json string which is having perl_script naming convention

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

We are working with the third party vendor who is passing following object as part of Form post

```
{
    "application": 123,
    "order_reference": "01234",
    "new_status": "initialize"
}
```

As this is not the standard naming convention in C#, i created following model.

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("application")]
    public string Application {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("order_reference")]
    public string OrderReference {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("new_status")]
    public string NewStatus {get; set;}
}
```

And i have below code in controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public Notify(Response response)
{
   // code.
}
```

The request is coming to the above method, but the object is not deserializing, I could see that, only `application` property is getting mapped.

Could any one  please let me know, whether i can make it work with the model i have created or do i have to create the same model as the response is coming?

Comment: Have you configured the app to use JSON.Net as the default JavaScript serializer?

Comment: @StephenMuecke : no, i have't. Not sure how to do that. And i dont want to make it default for all the Action method.

Comment: You can use this convention in C# for property names. Just use JASON.Stringify for your data in ajax request.

Comment: @AftabAhmed : Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Have a look at [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591750/setting-the-default-json-serializer-in-asp-net-mvc). If you don't want to use it as the default, then I think you will need make the parameter a string and use `Json.Net` to deserialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap your properties within in a json object and stringify it. I have tested it and it's working

```
   var Response = {
                response:{

                    'Application': "123",
                    'order_reference': "01234",
                    'new_status': "initialize"

                }
            };
```

C# Code to recieve Ajax Request

```
    [HttpPost]
    public Notify(Response response)
    {
        // code.
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public string Application { get; set; }

        public string order_reference { get; set; }

        public string new_status { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This works, but this is not a standard naming convention in C#. Any alternative to do this?

Comment: you can use any naming convention just wrap your object and stringify it.