# Custom JsonConverter not starting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I created a custom converter extending from `JsonConverter`, which would be used for an ASP.NET MVC and a Web API.

```
public class MyCustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

And I created this `CustomObject` that uses that converter:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyCustomJsonConverter))]
public class CustomObject
{
    ...
}
```

This converter work correctly for second application (WebApi), that means method of `ReadJson` are running after calling it in `TestOfUsingJson`. And in this case I didn't have to set up anything.

For the first application (ASP.NET MVC) I have a trouble, object are converted from json, but this object are not created from my custom converter. Method of `ReadJson` are not running.

Method which who use custom converter are looks same on the every application

```
public HttpResponseMessage TestOfUsingJson([FromBody] CustomObject objs)
{
    ...
}
```

Some settings for Json Serializer in the ASP.NET MVC's `Global.asax.cs`:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new MyCustomJsonConverter() }
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is this being used in the MVC application?  the default serializer for mvc is JavaScriptSerializer, not Json.net.  you need to tell mvc to user Json.net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the default JSON serializer in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591750/setting-the-default-json-serializer-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @Fran: The default was changed from `JavascriptSerializer` to `Json.NET` at some point (at least with Core, possibly earlier).  It's dependent on the version of MVC being used.

Comment: @SamAxe The OP doesn't mention Core and as of mvc5 you still needed to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared some solution that may be useful for someone

> Create binding model

```
public class BindJson : IModelBinder
{
    public BindJson()
    {

    }

    public virtual object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
            throw new SysException("Missing controller context");

        if (!controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return null;

        controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
        {
            var data = reader.ReadToEnd();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyText))
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, bindingContext.ModelType);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

> Assign binder in Global.asax.cs

```
..
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(BindJson), new BindJson());
..
```

> Assign binder into class

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(BindJson))]
public class CustomObject
{
    ...
}
```

> Call binder in method

```
public HttpResponseMessage TestOfUsingJson(CustomObject objs)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: you've just recreated what [JsonDotNetValueProviderFactory](https://github.com/DalSoft/JsonDotNetValueProviderFactory/blob/master/JsonDotNetValueProviderFactory/JsonValueProviderFactory.cs) with more steps.