# JsonIgnore not working in System.Web.Mvc.Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

I have a web-API project and a simple class with a few properties, some are marked `<JsonIgnore>`.

In my MVC-controller I put `Return Json(instanceOfMyClass, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`. All members are serialized.
I put `Return Json(Of MyClass)(instanceOfMyClass)` in my WEBAPI-controller. Only the members I intend to serialize are present.

How can I ignore these properties independent of the controller that's going to serialize.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `JsonResult` in MVC does not actually use JSON.NET which is why `[JsonIgnore]` is not working.  Instead it uses the `JavaScriptSerializer` class.

To make the `JavaScriptSerializer` skip a property, you can you the `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute on your model property.

An alternative would be to make a custom `ActionResult` that uses JSON.NET's `JsonConvert` to serialize the object which would then honor the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute.

Comment: Any example? :)

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps anyone, it didn't seem possible or straightforward to use [ScriptIgnore] in my .net Core app, so I did this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/json";
    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instanceOfMyClass));
}
```